# qTip-2 jquery - change plugin?

Tags: jquery, plugins, qtip

Hey there i just read the documenation from a nice jquery-plugin, i also read some demonstrations and i just wondered if i can change this:

http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/T9GHJ/

can this be changed to a list?
I mean,
Instead of:

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td></td>
```

Use:

```
<ul>
    <li></li> // ..
```

Is this possible? greetings

Comment: but your script is not working ! please add plugin script to your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***Yes***](http://jsfiddle.net/QqER5/)

**HTML**

```
<ul id="ul1">
    <li data-browser="firefox">Firefox</li>
    <li data-browser="ie">IE</li>
    <li data-browser="opera">Opera</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$("#ul1").on('mouseenter', 'li[data-browser]', function (event) {
    var browser = $(this).data('browser');

    $(this).qtip({
        overwrite: false,
        content: '<img src="http://media1.juggledesign.com/qtip2/images/browsers/64-' + browser + '.png" alt="' + browser + '"/>',
        position: {
            my: 'right center',
            at: 'left center',
            target: $(this),
            viewport: $('#ul1')
        },
        show: {
            event: event.type,
            ready: true
        },
        hide: {
            fixed: true
        }
    }, event); // Note we passed the event as the second argument. Always do this when binding within an event handler!

});
```

Comment: yea i passed it here: http://test81063.test-account.com/info/test.php    you can take a look on the source code, its exactly the same, but i doesnt work, any idea´s ?

Comment: It works, but the `li`s have 100% width so it's getting shown past the width of the page. Try setting the width of the `li`s or its container.

Answer (score 1):

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/

The example here works on List , so the answer is yes you can !!

```
$('ul:last li.active').qtip({
   content: 'This is an active list element',
   show: 'mouseover',
   hide: 'mouseout'
})
```

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/#structure

Comment: qTip 1 will be soon obsolete, better change to qTip 2